# How to take out common array from array of object

Tags: javascript

How to take out common array from array of object.

I have object of arrays.

```
var myObj = {
        0 : [{"result":"AC","id":847}]
        1 : [{"result":"AC","id":847},{"result":"BC","id":852}],
        2 : ["result":"AC","id":847}],
        3 : [{"result":"AC","id":847}]}
```

In this case I have `{"result":"AC","id":847}` is common in all array element,
how tocompare and print only common element across the array inside `myObj`

Here is what I am trying.

Comment: How do you still show up here with nothing more than “any idea”, with 3.5k rep on your account already? You should know about what [ask] explains by now, no?

Comment: Your object isn't correct, Javascript Object are of type `key/value` pair

Comment: You can also add how the expected result  will be after

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, the Object is not the best option for collections, if you can change I recommend you to use Array.

In this case with your Object you can do something like:

```
Object.keys(myObj).map(key=>{
 // here you have one by one each a key of the object
 //  myObj[key] will have the array
})
```

in the case of numbers of arrays are always the same you can destruct your object:

```
const [1,2,3,4,5] = myObj;
```

then each of them will be available as a const in your scope.

To answer your question:

```
    const fullCollection = [];
    let common = {};
    let occurrences = 0;
    Object.keys(myObj).map(key=>{
         // here you have one by one each a key of the object
         //  myObj[key] will have the array
          
          myObj[key].map(el=>{
              fullCollection.push(el);
          });
        })

    fullCollection.forEach(obj1={
    let temp = fullCollection.filter((obj) => JSON.encode(obj1) === JSON.encode(obj2));
       if(temp.length > occurences){
            common = temp[0];
            occurences = temp.length;
        }
    });
    
console.log('the most common object is: ', common, 'with :', occurrences, 'occurrences');
```

**Note:** I couldn't test it, but this may give you an idea of how to solve your problem.
**Note2:** I use JSON.encode to compare objects but you're free to use the way you want.